# What is the difference between the numbering of the same gate?

Tags: airport

What is the difference and purpose of having two taxilines for the same gate where one would be numbered gate 60 and the other 60A.

[image: Gate Example]
(Shown above: KSLC Gate A19 with A19A besides it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to allow efficient use of apron space when accommodating aircraft of different sizes. Rather than making every stand large enough for the largest possible aircraft that might use it (which would take up a lot of space), it is common to have overlapping stands where a large aircraft will essentially take up two or more stands, while smaller aircraft can park side by side.

One example: Two smaller aircraft may be parked side by side, one on stand 1L and one on 1R, blocking stand 1C. In case a larger aircraft needs to park here, it will park in the middle, on stand 1C, blocking 1L and 1R. *(Or just ignore the lines altogether and park in the middle of everything, as shown on the image ...)*

[image: EKAH stand 1]

Similar situation here. If you look closely, you can see the central yellow line has stopping positions for larger aircraft (MD11, B747, A300, ...) while the adjacent lines have stopping positions for relatively smaller aircraft (B737, ALL PROPS, ...)

[image: EKCH stand 130]

It could also be that different types of aircraft needs to park in different ways. Here, the solid yellow line is used when parking helicopters, while the dotted yellow line is for parking props.

[image: EKCH stand 111]

Comment: The aircraft in your first image isn't ignoring the lines. It is parking on the white line, which is a self-positioning parking position. It allows exiting the stand under own power without needing pushback.

Comment: @Bianfable Actually the white line you see is the old markings, which have been painted over because they repositioned the stands (used to be yellow). They still used that position for a transition periode until the new markings were finished :) And you are right that the old stand allowed leaving the stand by own power